# How to call the bean with the separator in the name to flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have a bean

```
<bean name="api.HelloWorld" class="ru.example.api.HelloWorld"/>
```

When you call in flow I get an error.

```
<evaluate expression="api.HelloWorld.test()"/>
```

How to call?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SpEL, you can use this:

```
<evaluate expression="@'api.HelloWorld'.test()"/>
```

if you are using OGNL or jboss-el, I don't think it can be done other than using a utility class, like this:

```
@Component
public class WebFlowUtil {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Object getBean(String beanName) {
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanName);
    }
}
```

then use:

```
<evaluate expression="webFlowUtil.getBean('api.HelloWorld').test()"/>
```

Comment: ERROR: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception
ognl.ParseException: Encountered " "\'" "\'api.HelloWorld\' "" at line 1, column 2.
Was expecting one of:
    "@" ...
    <IDENT> ...
 at ognl.OgnlParser.generateParseException(OgnlParser.java:3172)
 at ognl.OgnlParser.jj_consume_token(OgnlParser.java:3051)

Comment: did you escape the single quotes?

Comment: anyway, it looks like you are using OGNL so I don't think it will work, as I stated in my answer

Comment: added a workaround that should work with OGNL and jboss-el (tested with jboss-el)